# Python & Beautiful Soup/Requests: request return a byte string - how to decode?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding, python-requests

**Short version:** Scraping two very similar web pages, but the content of one is returned as a byte stream.

**Long version:** I am just dipping my toes into Beautiful Soup.  And I am testing on two web pages; both being lists of conference papers.  One list is "invited papers"; the other list is of "regular papers".  They both look the same (aside from the content): the papers are given in a table on each page.  And so on the first page I can do:

```
inv_papers = requests.get('https://my_conference.org/invited.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(inv_papers.text, 'html.parser')
datas = soup.find_all("td")
for all data in datas:
    text = ' '.join(data.text.split())
    print(text)
```

There's a lot of extra stuff in there, but I can just delete that by hand (or learn Beautiful Soup to extract from only part of a web page).

However, something in the regular papers page trips up requests and returns a string of bytes:

```
reg_papers = requests.get('https://my_conference.org/regular.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(reg_papers.text, 'html.parser')
```

I've found that both `inv_papers.header` and `reg_papers.header` are identical except for the date (one day apart) and the size.  But the content is different (only the first few lines are shown):

```
inv_papers.content

b'<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"\r\nxmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"\r\nxmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"\r\nxmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"\r\nxmlns:m="http://schema

reg_papers.content

b'\xff\xfe<\x00h\x00t\x00m\x00l\x00 \x00x\x00m\x00l\x00n\x00s\x00:\x00v\x00=\x00"\x00u\x00r\x00n\x00:\x00s\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00s\x00-\x00m\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00-\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00:\x00v\x00m\x00l\x00"\x
```

As you see, `inv_papers` returns its contents in ascii text; `reg_papers` as a raw byte stream.  I've tried:

```
reg_papers.content.decode('utf-8')
```

to receive the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I've also had a look at the page source of each page, and I can't see what might might be tripping the request up like this.

How do I get the web page material in useful text form?

*Addendum:* If I save the page source of the second page to a file, I can open it up as a local file and parse it fine with Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Did you notice the syntax error in your code?

Comment: The encoding is `'utf-16le'`, not `'utf-8'`. A dead giveaway is the BOM at the start `b'\xff\xfe'`

Comment: CtrlZ - no I didn't, but it might have been a typo!
tripleee - thank you very much; even decoding with `utf-16` worked perfectly.